# I cannot able to set the values to my adapter

Tags: android, amazon-ec2

java code :

```
public class Viewhirings extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Object> appliedmembersobj = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> appliedmembernames = new ArrayList<>();
String curmember,existhireobj;
RecyclerView rv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewhirings);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    curmember = bundle.getString("obj");
    existhireobj=bundle.getString("existhire");
    rv= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_recycler_view);
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("jobs");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                if (objects.size() > 0) {

                    for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                        appliedmembersobj = (ArrayList<Object>) object.getList("whoget");

                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No employee found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("awserror","left or right");
            }
        }
    });
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    for (int i=0;i<appliedmembersobj.size();i++){
        retriveinfo(String.valueOf(appliedmembersobj.get(i)));
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(appliedmembersobj.size()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String[] namesArray = new String[appliedmembernames.size()];
    namesArray = appliedmembernames.toArray(namesArray);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(namesArray);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void retriveinfo(String obj){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryloc = ParseQuery.getQuery("jobop");
    queryloc.whereEqualTo("objectId", obj);
    queryloc.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No name found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                        String s=object.getString("name");
                         String escape=String.valueOf(s);
                         Log.d("varudhu",escape);
                         appliedmembernames.add(escape);
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

I cannot able to set values to my adapter , when i indent the adapter i doesn't show me any value , but when i log the values it showing me the values , i think that's because of my find inbackground method is running background so i cannot able to get the values at the same time , but i dont know the alternatives

This is my adapter code

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private String[] mDatasetname;
private Integer[] mDatasetearnings;
private Integer[] mDatasetrat;
private Integer[] mtotaljobs;
private String[] mid;
private Float[] mrest;
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
     public  TextView totaljobs;
    public  TextView rest;
    public RatingBar rate;
 public MyViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        rate= (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_blah);
        totaljobs= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.idtotaljobs);
         rest=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.setrestid);

    }

}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset){
    mDatasetname = myDataset;
}
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDatasetname[position]);
    holder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("pos", mid[position]);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), mid[position],
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDatasetname.length; }
```

}

Comment: Could you share your adapter code?

Comment: yeah sir  i have added

Comment: Your main problem is that you are executing the query in background and your code keep running, so when you are setting the adapter the values of the array are empty and when your background code finished you are not refreshing the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                if (objects.size() > 0) {

                    for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                        appliedmembersobj = (ArrayList<Object>) object.getList("whoget");
retriveinfo(object);
                    }

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No employee found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("awserror","left or right");
            }
        }
    });
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(appliedmembersobj.size()),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



public void retriveinfo(String obj){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryloc = ParseQuery.getQuery("jobop");
    queryloc.whereEqualTo("objectId", obj);
    queryloc.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (object == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No name found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                        String s=object.getString("name");
                         String escape=String.valueOf(s);
                         Log.d("varudhu",escape);
                         appliedmembernames.add(escape);
String[] namesArray = new String[appliedmembernames.size()];
        namesArray = appliedmembernames.toArray(namesArray);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(namesArray);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```